# SLI with Nvidia GeForce GTX 480

Tags: nvidia-geforce, sli

I got a set of Nvidia GeForce GTX 480's but seem to have misplaced the SLI connector. I was looking to buy a new one but couldn't get a model number from the Nvidia website so I wasn't sure what one to get.

They seem to range in price anywhere from $3 to $99. Does anyone know how to figure out which one I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe most SLI Connectors are the same. You just need something like this [http://www.amazon.com/nVidia-NVIDIA-SLI-Connector/dp/B002BZ0D2C](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002BZ0D2C).